# Get screenshot (album) count in swift

Tags: ios, swift, phassetcollection

I am new to Swift and am trying to make a function that simply returns the number of photos in your screenshot album using fetchAssetCollections

I have

```
func getNumScreenshots() -> Int {

    let collection:PHFetchResult =  
     PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype:.smartAlbumScreenshots, options: nil)

    return collection.count
}
```

However, this is always returning 3, and I'm not sure why (I have 600 screenshots on my iPhone).

Comment: you can use smartAlbum

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
let albumsPhoto:PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection> = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: nil)

    albumsPhoto.enumerateObjects({(collection, index, object) in
        if collection.localizedTitle == "Screenshots"{
            let photoInAlbum = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: nil)
            print(photoInAlbum.count) //Screenshots albums count
        }
    })
```

Note: Use this code is Swift 3

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok Good luck !!

Comment: You can use NSPredicate directly to filter the photos.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 there is a very quick way to fetch `PHAssets` of just ScreenShots, without messy `if else`s:

Swift 4 :

```
let sc_Fetch = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: **.smartAlbumScreenshots**, options: nil).firstObject!

let sc_Assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: sc_Fetch , options: nil)

print("All ScreenShots Count : " , sc_Assets.count)
```